# Laravel Eloquent adding brackets to Eloquent SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Got a bit of an issue that I am banging my head against a brick wall about and done a lot of digging but cant seem to find an answer.

So I have a search query which is like this ( Excuse the roughness of the code ) more a concept.

```
 $slots = DB::table('slots')->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT user_id'));

 $slots->when( $date_start, function( $query, $date_start )  {
     return $query->where('start_date', '>=', $date_start->format('Y-m-d') );
 } );

 $slots->when( $date_end, function( $query, $date_end )  {
     return $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date_end->format('Y-m-d') );
 } );


 if( isset($dow)  ) {
   foreach( $days_array as $k => $v ) {
       if(isset($dow[$k])) {
            foreach($dow[$k] as $_k => $_v ) {
               if( !$dow_initial_where_added ) {
                    $slots->where('dow', '=', $v )
                       ->where('start_time', ">=", $thresholds[$_k]['start'] )
                       ->where('start_time', "<=", $thresholds[$_k]['end'] );
                       $dow_initial_where_added = true;
                } else {
                     $slots->orWhere('dow', '=', $v )
                         ->where('start_time', ">=", $thresholds[$_k]['start'] )
                         ->where('start_time', "<=", $thresholds[$_k]['end'] );      
                }                               
            }  
        }
}

$slots->where('status', '<', 3);

$slots->when( $instuctors_ids, function( $query, $instuctors_ids )  {
   return $query->whereIn('user_id', $instuctors_ids);
} );

$slots->get();
```

Now this works how I would of kind of expected and gives me something like this:

```
Select DISTINCT user_id from `slots` where `start_date` >= 2020-06-01 and `start_date` <= 2020-06-30 and `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 05:00 and `start_time` <= 11:59 or `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 12:00 and `start_time` <= 17:59 or `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 18:00 and `start_time` <= 23:59 and `status` < 3 and `user_id` in (15) order by RAND()
```

What I really need is for it to do this:

```
Select DISTINCT user_id from `slots` where (`start_date` >= 2020-06-01 and `start_date` <= 2020-06-30 and `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 05:00 and `start_time` <= 11:59 or `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 12:00 and `start_time` <= 17:59 or `dow` = thu and `start_time` >= 18:00 and `start_time` <= 23:59 and `status` < 3) and `user_id` in (15) order by RAND()
```

So brackets around everything apart from the And 'User_id' IN Statment.

I dont even know if its possible or not but would rather use Laravel's inbuilt query functions than write a raw query.

Answer (score 0):

Seems wrapping it all in a closure does the trick.

```
$slots = DB::table('slots')->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT user_id'))->where( function($query) use ($date_start, $date_end, $thresholds, $dow, $time, $days_array) {

    $query->when( $date_start, function( $query, $date_start )  {
                        return $query->where('start_date', '>=', $date_start->format('Y-m-d') );
    } );

    $query->when( $date_end, function( $query, $date_end )  {
        return $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date_end->format('Y-m-d') );
    } );

    $dow_initial_where_added = false;

    if( isset($dow)  ) {

        foreach( $days_array as $k => $v ) {
            if(isset($dow[$k])) {
                foreach($dow[$k] as $_k => $_v ) {
                    if( !$dow_initial_where_added ) {
                            $query->where('dow', '=', $v )
                                ->where('start_time', ">=", $thresholds[$_k]['start'] )
                                ->where('start_time', "<=", $thresholds[$_k]['end'] );
                                $dow_initial_where_added = true;
                    } else {
                            $query->orWhere('dow', '=', $v )
                                ->where('start_time', ">=", $thresholds[$_k]['start'] )
                                ->where('start_time', "<=", $thresholds[$_k]['end'] );

                     }
                }
            }
        }
    } 

});

$slots->where('status', '<', 3);

$slots->when( $instuctors_ids, function( $query, $instuctors_ids )  {
   return $query->whereIn('user_id', $instuctors_ids);
} );

$slots->get();
```